# Using both Opengl CORE functions along with Comptability profile - GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have this visual studio project where i can use both core and compat profile at the same time ,
by using : `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE)` ; but weirdly it doesn't work on another projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two different types of profiles (at least in OpenGL 3.2+): A core profile supports only core functionality. A compatibility profile supports core functionality + all deprecated functionality. There is no profile that doesn't allow for core functionality.

`GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE` means that you will get a profile type at random. This will either be a core or a compatibility profile (but it might be a different profile on different machines/drivers/applications). There is no way to predict which profile it will be.

From what you state, you simply want to use a compatibility profile.

Comment: Thanks, that mean that i should use the compatibility.